# OWIN Selfhost with webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware

Tags: .net, owin, webpack-hot-middleware, webpack-dev-middleware, self-host-webapi

I wonder if there any nuget package exists for integration of webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware with OWIN Selfhost full .Net46 like for AspNetCore - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices?

Comment: I haven't come across any, but I may try and build one soon!